# Set status bar colour in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios7-statusbar

Hi I am developing small Iphone application in which I am giving colour for my navigation bar like this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];    
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But because of this my status bar also become of red colour. I want to change it to white. I tried in followings way but those are not working for me.

in info.plist file I set `View controller-based status bar appearance = "NO"`

then in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` set `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];`

Then in UIViewcontroller

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

But above methods are not working for me. My navigation bar and status bar of same colour. I want to make status bar colour to white. My application is very simple having one UIView controller with one navigation controller. Am I doing some thing wrong? Need Help. Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` tells the status bar to display light colored text, but it is still transparent. And because the navigation controller reports the position of its navigation bar to be `UIBarPositionTopAttached`, you see the effect of the navigation bar's color stretching beneath the status bar.

Here are two ideas how to achieve what you are looking for:

<strike>Subclass the navigation controller, implement `- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar` and return `UIBarPositionTop`. This make the navigation bar not stretch beneath the status bar, and instead the superview of the navigation bar (which is usually white), will show.</strike>

Or, better, subclass the navigation controller, add a subview of 20pt height **above the navigation bar**, and in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, position and resize the subview correctly to orientation. Now you can give any color you'd like to this view, and it will be the color of the status bar.

**Edit:** Based on the comments, the `positionForBar:` approach may not work.

Comment: thank you for replay. I created custom navigation controller and implemented method as you said. That methods return UIBarPositionTop. In story board I set that class to my navigation controller. But still shows me my status of same colour as that navigation bar.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the method and see if it is called. Could be the system is doing something devious and not calling the method.

Comment: Yeah it get called. I checked it. but still problem remain same. In plist file I put view controller base status bar appearance property but still remain same. Need help. Thank you for replay

Comment: Then the second option maybe your only choice.

Comment: Ok will try and let you know whether works or not. But have you tried first option? Is it working for you? If it is then can you please share one sample code. Coz I feel I am doing some where wrong things.

Comment: @nilkash I just proposed ideas. The second will work for sure, but is a tad more complex. But why do you want the status bar white anyway? In iOS7, it is normal that the navigation bar extends under the status bar.

Comment: thank you for replay. I understand your second option. But why it is not working even though I set `View controller-based status bar appearance = "NO"`.

Comment: That is unrelated to the problem. No matter who sets the status bar appearance, it will remain transparent. Status bar appearance only controls the text color, not the background color.

Comment: ok. That mean it will make status bar transparent.Thank you Leo. Will try your second solution and let you know about it.